Need to split zeros after decimal but not left side zeros in python
Need to split zeros after decimal but not left side zeros in python
Input:
0001202406040252523670952717.00
Actual Output:
1202406040252523670952717
Expected Output:
0001202406040252523670952717
   def strip_function(num):
        return num.to_integral() if num == num.to_integral() else num.normalize()


what's the input? a string or a float?

Input is string

Please provide a [mre]. What is num? Is it a string? A decimal (from the methods you are trying to apply to it, it seems so. But we shouldn't have to guess. Besides, a decimal is a form of number. It doesn't store the representation with the useless 0. It does have equivalency class, meaning that there may be different representations, sign times coefficient times exponent-wise, of the same number. But not with 0 on the left. If your type is decimal, again, not supposed to guess, then, you'll have to find another type to store your number representation)

Ok, in the meantime, you clarify one of the question. But then, what do you expect methods to_integral and normalize to do on a string. There is no such method.

Does changing strip_function to  def strip_function(num): return num.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in num else num provide what you want?  This is from drop trailing zeros from decimal

You just need to rstrip any "0" then rstrip any ".":
X = "0001202406040252523670952717.00"

def strip_function(num: str) -> str:
    return num.rstrip("0").rstrip(".")

print(strip_function(X))

Output:
0001202406040252523670952717


So long as there actually is a . in the input. Try strip_function("50000").

@AKX From the question I quote "Need to split zeros after decimal..." the implication being that there will always be a decimal point

Fair – but adding the if "." not in num check might be a good idea to be sure :)
